# Android-11 "Only-This Time" Permission Behavior

Tags: android, android-11

In Android-11, If I choose `Only This Time` permission and access Camera then:

**Observed Behaviour:** `One-Time permission` stays granted for a few seconds (approx 3-5 sec) after we **kill** the application. If I re-open the application instantly or before this short period of time then the permission stays granted and If I re-open it after this short period of time then it will ask permission again and works fine.

**Expected Behaviour:** The permission will be revoked instantly after we kill the application instead of waiting for any specific period of time.

Is there any solution to it or is it a bug in Android-11? Also, nothing is mentioned in the documentation related to it. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#one-time

(P.S: All permission related checks are already implemented in the code.)

Comment: "after we kill the application" -- what precisely do you mean by this? "Is there any solution to it or is it a bug in Android-11?" -- probably neither, as the documentation is very unclear as to exactly when these permissions get revoked.

Comment: "After we kill the application"  means the app is in a killed state nor in the background neither in the foreground. @CommonsWare
And Yes documentation is very unclear about this.

Comment: I have observed the same behaviour on android 11 Pixel 4 :/

Comment: Just came across this too on my Pixel 3A XL with Android 11 - it seems like it does revoke the temporary permission after one minute when the app has been closed (back button, not killed/moved from recents) after 50 seconds it does not ask again, whereas after 1:05min it does ask and the app start takes a bit longer then - I could imagine this is on purpose so if you instantly go back to the app it will not annoy you again - and one minute is quite short. It's still irritating, since it says only "this" time..

Comment: @Ben yes there is a time period after which permissions are revoked. But that time period is not fixed as earlier it was approx 5 seconds but now its approx 1 min. Also there is no mention of this time period in any documentation. It will cause issue if it will vary.